# DESKey expanding using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, 3des, parity

I'm implementing a protocol in Node.js.
This protocol uses 3DES encryption in CBC mode, okay.

But to encrypt/decrypt I need to spread/expand the 14 bytes DES Key to 16 bytes just adding the parity bits. But. I'm stuck on it using JavaScript/Node.js.

I have some implementations using C and Python, can anyone help me to do the same using JavaScript/Node.js (my trial is below)?

```
uint8 *des_key_spread(uint8 *normal){
  static uint8 spread[16];

  spread[ 0] = normal[ 0] & 0xfe;
  spread[ 1] = ((normal[ 0] << 7) | (normal[ 1] >> 1)) & 0xfe;
  spread[ 2] = ((normal[ 1] << 6) | (normal[ 2] >> 2)) & 0xfe;
  spread[ 3] = ((normal[ 2] << 5) | (normal[ 3] >> 3)) & 0xfe;
  spread[ 4] = ((normal[ 3] << 4) | (normal[ 4] >> 4)) & 0xfe;
  spread[ 5] = ((normal[ 4] << 3) | (normal[ 5] >> 5)) & 0xfe;
  spread[ 6] = ((normal[ 5] << 2) | (normal[ 6] >> 6)) & 0xfe;
  spread[ 7] = normal[ 6] << 1;
  spread[ 8] = normal[ 7] & 0xfe;
  spread[ 9] = ((normal[ 7] << 7) | (normal[ 8] >> 1)) & 0xfe;
  spread[10] = ((normal[ 8] << 6) | (normal[ 9] >> 2)) & 0xfe;
  spread[11] = ((normal[ 9] << 5) | (normal[10] >> 3)) & 0xfe;
  spread[12] = ((normal[10] << 4) | (normal[11] >> 4)) & 0xfe;
  spread[13] = ((normal[11] << 3) | (normal[12] >> 5)) & 0xfe;
  spread[14] = ((normal[12] << 2) | (normal[13] >> 6)) & 0xfe;
  spread[15] = normal[13] << 1;

  des_key_parity_adjust(spread, 16);
  return spread;
}

void des_key_parity_adjust(uint8 *key, uint8 len){
  uint8 i, j, parity;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
      parity = 1;
      for (j = 1; j < 8; j++) 
        if ((key[i] >> j) & 0x1) parity = ~parity & 0x01;
      key[i] |= parity;
    }
}
```

From here [Python expand/spread](https://code.google.com/p/passlib/source/browse/passlib/utils/des.py?name=release-1.5#574)

My implementation:

```
function deskey_spread(normal){
  spread = new Buffer(16);
  spread[ 0] = normal[ 0] & 0xfe;
  spread[ 1] = ((normal[ 0] << 7) | (normal[ 1] >> 1)) & 0xfe;
  spread[ 2] = ((normal[ 1] << 6) | (normal[ 2] >> 2)) & 0xfe;
  spread[ 3] = ((normal[ 2] << 5) | (normal[ 3] >> 3)) & 0xfe;
  spread[ 4] = ((normal[ 3] << 4) | (normal[ 4] >> 4)) & 0xfe;
  spread[ 5] = ((normal[ 4] << 3) | (normal[ 5] >> 5)) & 0xfe;
  spread[ 6] = ((normal[ 5] << 2) | (normal[ 6] >> 6)) & 0xfe;
  spread[ 7] = normal[ 6] << 1;
  spread[ 8] = normal[ 7] & 0xfe;
  spread[ 9] = ((normal[ 7] << 7) | (normal[ 8] >> 1)) & 0xfe;
  spread[10] = ((normal[ 8] << 6) | (normal[ 9] >> 2)) & 0xfe;
  spread[11] = ((normal[ 9] << 5) | (normal[10] >> 3)) & 0xfe;
  spread[12] = ((normal[10] << 4) | (normal[11] >> 4)) & 0xfe;
  spread[13] = ((normal[11] << 3) | (normal[12] >> 5)) & 0xfe;
  spread[14] = ((normal[12] << 2) | (normal[13] >> 6)) & 0xfe;
  spread[15] = normal[13] << 1;

  des_key_parity_adjust(spread, 16);
  return spread;
}

function des_key_parity_adjust(key, len){
    var i = new Buffer(1);
    var j = new Buffer(1);
    var parity = new Buffer(1);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
      parity = 1;
      for (j = 1; j < 8; j++) 
        if ((key[i] >> j) & 0x1) parity = ~parity & 0x01;
      key[i] |= parity;
    }
}
```

My input:

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e
```

Output using C implementation:

```
01 80 80 61 40 29 19 0E 08 04 45 02 10 91 4C 29
```

And my Node.js implementation:

```
01 80 80 61 40 29 19 0e 08 04 43 40 b0 61 34 1c
```

Whats wrong? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct and is working properly.

The problem is the input, I used a normal array, not a Buffer.

Using Buffer the code works properly.

Input:

```
01 80 80 61 40 29 19 0E 08 04 45 02 10 91 4C 29
```

Using the C code:

```
01 80 80 61 40 29 19 0E 08 04 45 02 10 91 4C 29
```

Using my Node.js implementation

```
01 80 80 61 40 29 19 0E 08 04 45 02 10 91 4C 29
```

Thanks!